# Chromecast SDK Disconnects Connected Bluetooth Device

Tags: android, chromecast, android-bluetooth, google-cast

I've implemented an app that streams audio and video. The app also has chromecast support. Here's my issue: If I'm streaming audio to a connected bluetooth device, then I browse to an activity that attempts to discover chromecast devices, the bluetooth connection gets into a bad state (playback switches back to my device but the bluetooth connection says the bluetooth device is still connected). If I comment out the code that does chromecast device discovery, the bluetooth connection is fine. Here's the line of code that, when uncommented, causes the connect to terminate:

```
mMediaRouter.addCallback(mMediaRouteSelector, mMediaRouterCallback,
        MediaRouter.CALLBACK_FLAG_REQUEST_DISCOVERY);
```

Here's what I'm seeing in the logs:

```
10-29 18:30:31.098    843-10255/? D/NetlinkSocketObserver﹕ NeighborEvent{elapsedMs=1128444524, 10.0.0.1, [CCA4620B2A21], RTM_NEWNEIGH, NUD_REACHABLE}
10-29 18:30:31.429     843-1680/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Permission Denial: Accessing service ComponentInfo{com.google.android.music/com.google.android.music.dial.DialMediaRouteProviderService} from pid=12704, uid=10386 that is not exported from uid 10060
10-29 18:30:31.436    1805-1805/? I/Keyboard.Facilitator﹕ onFinishInput()
10-29 18:30:31.450    198-14249/? I/bt_a2dp_hw﹕ out_set_parameters: state 1
10-29 18:30:31.450    198-14249/? I/str_params﹕ key: 'routing' value: '128'
10-29 18:30:31.450    198-14249/? I/str_params﹕ key: 'a2dp_sink_address' value: 'BC:85:56:38:15:B2'
10-29 18:30:31.459  12704-13205/com.testapp.android W/AudioTrack﹕ dead IAudioTrack, PCM, creating a new one from obtainBuffer()
10-29 18:30:31.470      198-835/? D/audio_hw_primary﹕ out_set_parameters: enter: usecase(1: low-latency-playback) kvpairs: routing=2
10-29 18:30:31.480      198-834/? D/audio_hw_primary﹕ select_devices: out_snd_device(2: speaker) in_snd_device(0: none)
10-29 18:30:31.480      198-834/? D/msm8974_platform﹕ platform_send_audio_calibration: sending audio calibration for snd_device(2) acdb_id(15)
10-29 18:30:31.480      198-834/? D/audio_hw_primary﹕ enable_snd_device: snd_device(2: speaker)
10-29 18:30:31.483      198-834/? D/audio_hw_primary﹕ enable_audio_route: apply and update mixer path: low-latency-playback
10-29 18:30:31.535     843-1911/? W/AudioTrack﹕ dead IAudioTrack, PCM, creating a new one from processAudioBuffer()
10-29 18:30:31.565      198-835/? D/audio_hw_primary﹕ out_set_parameters: enter: usecase(1: low-latency-playback) kvpairs: routing=2
10-29 18:30:31.961  14798-14798/? D/ChimeraCfgMgr﹕ Loading module com.google.android.gms.cast from APK com.google.android.gms
10-29 18:30:31.966  14798-14340/? D/MdnsClient﹕ Multicast lock held. Releasing
10-29 18:30:31.967  14798-14340/? D/MdnsClient﹕ #acquireLock. Multicast lock not held. Acquiring
10-29 18:30:33.424  12704-13190/com.testapp.android D/com.testapp.android.sqlite.LocalPlaybackPositionTableHelper﹕ - updated playback position to 23
10-29 18:30:34.530    198-14249/? I/bt_a2dp_hw﹕ suspend_audio_datapath: state 1
10-29 18:30:34.533  14175-14200/? E/bt_btif﹕ bta_av_str_stopped:audio_open_cnt=1, p_data ab20aea4
10-29 18:30:34.533  14175-14200/? W/bt_btif﹕ bta_dm_rm_cback:2, status:6
10-29 18:30:34.576  14175-14200/? W/bt_btif﹕ bta_dm_rm_cback:2, status:6
10-29 18:30:34.584    198-14249/? I/bt_a2dp_hw﹕ skt_disconnect: fd 25
10-29 18:30:34.584  14175-14214/? E/bt_btif﹕ warning : no command pending, ignore ack
10-29 18:30:34.584  14175-14214/? W/bt_btif﹕ pcm bytes per tick 3528
10-29 18:30:34.584  14175-14193/? I/BluetoothA2dpServiceJni﹕ bta2dp_audio_state_callback
10-29 18:30:34.585  14175-14213/? D/A2dpStateMachine﹕ Connected process message: 101
10-29 18:30:34.585  14175-14213/? D/A2dpStateMachine﹕ A2DP Playing state : device: BC:85:56:38:15:B2 State:10->11
```

I'm testing on a Nexus 5 running Android 6.0. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: So after a bunch of tests I found out that I was erroneously doing the following if no media route was selected:

```
mMediaRouter.selectRoute(mMediaRouter.getDefaultRoute());
```

This was causing the bluetooth connection to be lost.